# Trigger Workflow on dependent component change

Tags: workflow

Is it possible to trigger the workflow whenever dependent component edited? E.g. Lets say workflow has been applied on the article component which include image component linking, normal component linking. I want my article workflow to be trigger whenever content author edited the linked image component directly.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's possible since 2011 I believe. You can create event handler which will kick in when linked component is saved. Inside the handler you can figure out what related items should have workflow triggered and create a new process instance with those items.